# == operator overloading with struct

Tags: c++

I'm trying to define an == operator within a struct, like this:

```
struct names {
    string fname;
    string lname;
bool operator==(names a, names b) {
    return (a.fname == b.lname);
}
};
```

However, the compiler says:

> ..\src\trash.cpp:10:33: error: 'bool names::operator==(names, names)' must take exactly one argument

Why is this?

Comment: You are doing the overload as a nonstatic member function, so it has an implicit object parameter already.

Comment: Make it a non-member.

Comment: And preferably not taking its arguments by value.

Comment: Your first assumption should be that the compiler is right, then go from there.

Comment: BTW, you compare different fields... (so the comparison is not symmetrical)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you overload a binary operator as a *member function*, then it should only take one argument. The first operand is the object the operator is called on (i.e. `*this`); the second operand is the single function argument.

```
struct names {
    //...

    // better to pass by reference;
    // make the function 'const' so it can be used on constant objects
    bool operator==(names const & rhs) const {
        return this->fname == rhs.lname;
    }
};
```

Alternatively, you can overload it as a *non-member function*, with two arguments:

```
bool operator==(names const & lhs, names const & rhs) {
    return lhs.fname == rhs.lname;
}
```

If this needed access to private members (which isn't the case in this example), then it would have to be a friend. You can define friends inside the class definition; in which case the code would look exactly the same as your example, only with `friend` in front of the function declaration.

<sub>(Of course, this isn't a sensible definition of equality since it's not symmetric. Many algorithms will break if you can have `a == b` but not `b==a`, as you can with this definition. `lhs.fname == rhs.fname && lhs.lname == rhs.lname` would make more sense.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

`operator==` is meant to compare two objects for equality. You have it appearing to compare the first and last names for different objects, presumably to catch duets like George Lazenby and Emma George.

I'd make it a member function of the class and use `this` for one of the objects:

```
bool operator== (const names &rhs) const {
    return (this->fname == rhs.fname) && (this->lname == rhs.lname);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do:

- As member function:

  ```
  struct names {
      string fname;
      string lname;

      bool operator==(const names& rhs) const { /* Your code */ }
  };
  ```
- or as free function:

  ```
  bool operator==(const names& lhs, const names& rhs) const { /* Your code */ }
  ```